# How to call Provider as Future in FutureBuilder?

Tags: api, flutter, flutter-layout

I try to call provider in my `FutureBuilder` as below:

```
initState() {
setState(() {
  tankProvider = Provider.of<TankDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
  _data = tankProvider.getTankData(context);
});

// tankInfo = Provider.of<TankInfoProvider>(context, listen: false);
// tankInfo.getTankInfo(context);

Services.fetchInfo().then((tankInfos){
  setState(() {
    tankInfo = tankInfos;
  });
});
super.initState();


 }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ping = Provider.of<TankPingProvider>(context);
    return FutureBuilder<Map<String, Tank>>(
      future: Services.fetchData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
```

But I receive error as below:

```
The argument type 'TankPingProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Map<String, Tank>>'.
```

Is there anyway I can remove this error and use provider as a future in FutureBuilder?

Comment: `Future.value(somethingYouWantAsAFuture)`

Comment: You never need setState inside an initState.  At the end of initState, you're about to call build anyway.

Comment: Looks like you haven't fixed this though. "Services.fetchData()".  No, that does not belong in your FutureBuilder.  The *future* that that returns should be put into a variable in your initState, and then that variable should be used for the "future: someVar".

Comment: Hi All. Thank You for the comment. Thank you @RandalSchwartz for the answer. Is there an article that you can share about calling setState? Because you siad i don't need to call setState inside of initState, so I want to read about that because I still new to flutter

Comment: Not sure how I learned it... I've read so much over the past many years. ;)  But these docs are worth reading: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz do I need to add setState inside of the state lifecycle when needed or non at all especially in the didChangeDependencies?

Comment: setState is primarily used in build() or in the callbacks set up from build().  I can't think of any other time at the moment.  Definitely not initState or didChangeDependencies.

Comment: So, never call setState in the state lifecycle?